# how can we rewrite the sql syntax to griddb syntax?

Tags: griddb

i am trying to create the library in which i want to use SQL to on top of griddb architecture like in SQL

```
select * from table
```

in database table select * works to select all of the record from database table. but in containerize griddb  how this works with alternate of select *.